# Having issues sorting an array by an integer as opposed to a float. multiple errors

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting

I am trying to sort by the number of fans entered as opposed to the price of tickets but when I change sales to fans I get an error.  I think it has something to do with how it is being initialized but I am new to all of this and I am lost in the sauce.

I have tried changing the entire code so that fans is a float but that screwed everything up.

```
void switchRows (int m, int n) {
  char tc;
  int  ti;
  float v;
  // printf ("Switching %d with %d\n", m, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
    tc = group [m][i];
    group [m][i] = group [n][i];
    group [n][i] = tc;
  } // end for each character in a group name
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXC; i++) {
    ti = fans [m][i];
    fans [m][i] = fans [n][i];
    fans [n][i] = ti;
  } // end for each fan category
  v = sales [m];
  sales [m] = sales [n];
  sales [n] = v;
} // end switch



int findMinSales (int m) {
  int min = fans [m];
  int target = m;
  for (int i = m+1; i < count; i++)
    if (fans [i] < min) {
      min = fans [i];
      target = i;
    } // end new max found
  return target;
} // end function findMinSales




void sortBySales () {
  int target;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    target = findMinSales (i);
    if (target < i)
      switchRows (i, target);
  } // for each concert
} // end function sortBySales
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'int [4]' [-Wint-conversion]
                                          int min = fans [m];
                                                                   ^     ~~~~~~~~
                                                                                 main.c:82:18: warning: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('int *' and 'int')
                                                                           if (fans [i] < min) {
     ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
                   main.c:83:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int [4]' [-Wint-conversion]
                                            min = fans [i];
                                                                     ^ ~~~~~~~~
                                                                               3 warnings generated
```

Comment: You have lots of variables here but we don't know the types of any of them. Can you share the declaration of variables?

Comment: Here is how the code starts:                                                                        #define MAXW 100 // max characters in welcome 
#define MAXN 100 // max characters in a group/concert name
#define MAXG  50 // max concerts/groups
#define MAXC   4 // max categories
#define MAXT   1 //total sales


char welcome [MAXW];
char  group  [MAXG][MAXN];
int   fans   [MAXG][MAXC];
float prices [MAXC];
float sales  [MAXG];
float total  [MAXT];
int   count = 0;

Comment: sorry about the formatting. Im new to these threads too.

Comment: @glts2814 Code in comments is hard to read. Can you edit your question with that information, please? There's an edit button at the bottom left. We also need to see how you're calling these functions.

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing how 'fans' was initialized - but it looks like you are not dereferencing pointers correctly ie. `int min = *fans[m]`

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: dereferencing the pointers was spot on. Thank you!!